# question about how navigate fast in directory

Tags: command-line

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAE9z.png)

if i want to go to ObliqueShock I need to write: cd ObliqueShock
so every time i need to go in a specific folder i have to copy and paste the directory where i want to go, is it possible to write for example only cd and the first letter of the folder and the system will read automatically the directory where i want to go without write every single time the folder?

Answer (score 0):

First suggestion: Tab completion. You can type a few letters of a filename and press tab for autocompletion.

```bash
$ cd O # press tab here, it will be autocompleted to the following
$ cd ObliqueShock
```

Second suggestion: Some shells, such as [fish](https://fishshell.com/) and [Zsh](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-autocomplete) have an autocomplete feature. While typing, you see one suggestion, which you can execute without typing the whole command

Answer (score 0):

If you start to type the directory, hit <kbd>tab</kbd> and bash will autocomplete if there is only one option.

So if, in you your current working directory, there is only one folder beginning with `O`, then once you’ve typed `cd O` you can hit <kbd>tab</kbd> and it’ll autocomplete the rest of the name.